# Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView" to "Login"

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, .net

I encountered this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView" to "Login"
```

The error occured on Line 26.

```
Source Error:

Line 26:         Login Login1 =(System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
Line 27:         TextBox UserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
Line 28:         TextBox FailureText = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("FailureText");
```

and I had declare the following as my namespaces. But errors still remained.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting to `LoginView`:

```
(System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)
```

And expecting to get: `Login`

```
Login Login1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)....
```

**Change to:**

```
LoginView Login1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
```

Or:

```
Login Login1 = (Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
```

Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I had did according to what you said. However, this error appear
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView'.
source error:Line 26:             LoginView Login1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");

Comment: @user1467175. Than the control is `Login` Use this `Login Login1 = (Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");`

Comment: now it changed to Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' to type 'Login'.

Comment: for the above posted code, i am trying to retrieve the data from Login(which is inside the LoginView)

Comment: @user1467175. So: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login login = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login) LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");`

Comment: Thanks! It really solved my errors. Thanks for being so patience (:

Answer (score 0):

Change line 26 from this

```
Login Login1 =(System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
```

to this

```
LoginView Login1 =(System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
```

It's throwing an exception because your variable isn't a LoginView object